# DELPHI. Programm is compiling. but nothing happens with form

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

Compile is running, all ok. But nothing happens with form.
The form is launched, but no data is automatically added to it. If you enter the data manually, then when you press the button, nothing happens either

It is necessary to display the table of values ​​of the function Y (x) and its expansions in the series S (x) for x varying from x0 to xk with step h = (x0-xk) / 10. The proximity of the values ​​of S (x) and Y (x) in the entire range of values ​​of x indicates the correctness of calculating S (x) and Y (x).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,ExtCtrls ;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Form1Create(Sender:TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender:TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := '0';
  Edit2.Text := '2';
  Edit3.Text := '5';
  Edit4.Text := '0.25';
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Lab3, Kosyakova Dasha, 10702217');
  Button1Click(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject);
var
  x1, x2, x, h, a, s  : extended;
  N, k, c             : integer;
begin
   x1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('x1 = ' + Edit1.Text);
   x2 := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('x2 = ' + Edit2.Text);
   N := StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('N = ' + Edit3.Text);
   h :=StrToFloat(Edit4.Text);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('h = ' + Edit4.Text);
   C :=-1;
   X := x1;
   Repeat
     A := 1;
     S := 1;
     for k :=1 to N do
     begin
        a := c*a*x/k;
        s := s + a;
     end;
     Memo1.Lines.Add(
       'npи x = ' + FloatToStrF(x, ffFixed, 6, 2) + ' сумма = ' +
       FloatToStrF(s, ffFixed, 6,2));
     x := x+h;
   until x>x2;
end;

end.
```

Comment: "Nothing happens with form" isn't a very helpful error report.Can you give some more detail?

Comment: The form is launched, but no data is automatically added to it. If you enter the data manually, then when you press the button, nothing happens either

Comment: Ok, you need to edit your question to put that important bit of information into it. Your questions are more likely to get useful answers if they include explanations of what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: If you are from Russia you also can ask your future questions on [StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)

Answer (score 9):

The only explanation for what you report is that you failed to connect the events to their handlers.

- Click on the form design surface.
- Switch to the *Object Inspector*.
- Select the *Events* page.
- Locate the `OnCreate` event, and set its value to `Form1Create`.

You may need to do the same for the button, to connect its `OnClick` event to the handler.

Comment: I believe it so... the code may be inserted with something like Copy / Paste or any other methods and events are not related properly!